# Cannot run sass after installing

Tags: ruby, node.js, macos, sass

I have sass installed on my Mac but every time I try to run I get this error.

I am on a Mac with OSX 10.9.4
Ruby 1.9.3

```
Andrews-iMac:~ andrewcorliss$ sass -v
/Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': dlopen(/Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/digest/sha1.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/digest/sha1.bundle
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass/engine.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sass-3.3.14/lib/sass.rb:104:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sass-3.3.14/bin/sass:8:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sass-3.3.14/bin/sass:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/sass:19:in `load'
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/sass:19:in `<main>'
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /Users/andrewcorliss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `libcrypto` installed in `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I finally found the Answer.  I did not have node or ruby on rails properly installed on my machine.  Once doing a clean and installing it fresh everything worked fine.